# Recursive function with loops inside

Tags: swift, loops, recursion

I am trying to generalize loops within a recursive function...

The basic double loop is the following function:

```
func multiLoops(start ix:Int, upTo n:Int) {
    for i in ix...n {
        for j in i+1 ... n+1 {
            print("it is \(i) \(j)")
        }
    }
}
multiLoops(start: 3, upTo: 6)
```

With the following result:

```
it is 3 4
it is 3 5
it is 3 6
it is 3 7
it is 4 5
it is 4 6
it is 4 7
it is 5 6
it is 5 7
it is 6 7
```

My tentative to do the same with a recursive function is the following:

```
func multiLoopsRecursive(start ix:Int, upTo n:Int, loopNumber:Int){
    var loopNumber = loopNumber
    var previous_i = ix
    
    func loop(start ix:Int, upTo n:Int) {
        for i in ix + 1...n {
            print("it is \(previous_i) \(i)")
            if loopNumber > 1 {
                loopNumber -= 1
                previous_i = i
            loop(start: previous_i+1, upTo: n+loopNumber)
            }
        }
    }
    loop(start: ix, upTo: n)
}
multiLoopsRecursive(start: 3, upTo: 6, loopNumber: 2)
```

With the following result ...

```
it is 3 4
it is 4 6
it is 4 7
it is 4 5
it is 4 6
```

Not really the same as the basic double loop ...
I am really blocked...
Thank you for your help...
Regards
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are !
The trick is to know in which loop you are to adapt the different variables. I leave in the code the « print loop down and up » for more clarity, but it can be suppressed of course.
Now it works with loops in loops :-)

```
func loopInLoop (iStart:Int, iEnd:Int, numberOfLoops : Int) {
    print("what loop is it! \(loopIndex)")
    var iRank = 0
    
    for i in iStart...(iEnd - numberOfLoops + loopIndex) {
        iArray[loopIndex-1] = i 
        iRank += 1
        if loopIndex < numberOfLoops {
            print ("loop down")
            loopIndex += 1
            loopInLoop(iStart: iStart + iRank, iEnd: iEnd, numberOfLoops: numberOfLoops)
            
        } else {print("iArray:\(iArray)")}
    }
    print ("loop up")
    loopIndex -= 1
}

let iStart = 3 // initial starting index of first loop, must be <= iEnd
let iEnd = 7 // ending starting index of first loop
let numberOfLoops = 2 // number of loop to execute, must be <= (iEnd-iStart)

var iArray = [Int](repeating: 0, count: numberOfLoops) // Array of indexes
var loopIndex = 1 // initial index of the loop

loopInLoop(iStart: iStart, iEnd: iEnd, numberOfLoops : numberOfLoops)
```

Result:

```
what loop is it! 1
loop down
what loop is it! 2
iArray:[3, 4]
iArray:[3, 5]
iArray:[3, 6]
iArray:[3, 7]
loop up
loop down
what loop is it! 2
iArray:[4, 5]
iArray:[4, 6]
iArray:[4, 7]
loop up
loop down
what loop is it! 2
iArray:[5, 6]
iArray:[5, 7]
loop up
loop down
what loop is it! 2
iArray:[6, 7]
loop up
loop up
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic double loop with a print loopNumber added:

```
    for i in ix...n {
        print("it is loop 1")
        for j in i+1 ... n+1 {
            print("it is loop 2")
            print("it is \(i) \(j)")
        }
    }
}
multiLoops(start: 3, upTo: 6)
```

Result:

```
it is loop 1
it is loop 2
it is 3 4
it is loop 2
it is 3 5
it is loop 2
it is 3 6
it is loop 2
it is 3 7
it is loop 1
it is loop 2
it is 4 5
it is loop 2
it is 4 6
it is loop 2
it is 4 7
it is loop 1
it is loop 2
it is 5 6
it is loop 2
it is 5 7
it is loop 1
it is loop 2
it is 6 7
```

Larme, Please find your code with the loopNumber added:

```
var loopNumber = 1
func multiLoopsRecursive(start: Int, upTo: Int) {
    print("it is loop \(loopNumber)")
    for i in start+1...upTo+1 {
        print("it is \(start) \(i)")
    }
    let newStart = start + 1
    if newStart < upTo+1 {
        loopNumber += 1
        multiLoopsRecursive(start: newStart, upTo: upTo)
    }
}

print("Recursive")
multiLoopsRecursive(start: 3, upTo: 6)
```

Result:

```
Recursive
it is loop 1
it is 3 4
it is 3 5
it is 3 6
it is 3 7
it is loop 2
it is 4 5
it is 4 6
it is 4 7
it is loop 3
it is 5 6
it is 5 7
it is loop 4
it is 6 7
```

Thank you for your support
K